# I can not access the array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sending an array from javascript to PHP file. When doing echo $newArray inside the .php file, it shows me the array correctly:

> array(4) { ["titulo"]=> string(28) "Curso de canvas y Javascript
>   ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["valorItem"]=> string(2)
>   "10"["idProducto"]=> string(3) "403" }
>   array(4) { ["titulo"]=>
>   string(15) "Curso de jQuery" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["valorItem"]=> string(2) "10"["idProducto"]=> string(3) "402" }

**How do I access some element of the array?** I have tried with this:

```
$newArray = $_POST["array"];

$title = json_decode($newArray[0]["titulo"]);

echo $title;
```

But this appears:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'titulo' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\controladores\carrito.controlador.php on line
>   78

I tried everything that says in other questions of this type in the stack, but it has not worked

Comment: Where does that `[0]` come from? And why `json_decode()`?

Comment: Your first output would not be the result of `echo` but of `var_dump`. Or are you really saying that you get *that* with `echo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @trincot I get that answer by doing echo. if I do var_dump I get the same answer but in string format.

Comment: @Siguza It's what they recommended in other answers, that's why I tried that

Answer (score 0):

where is your javascript? You can do something like

```
$title = $_POST['titulo']
```

similarly do other things

Comment: In an hour I will try this